# OpenCL output values overwritten on CPU

Tags: opencl, memory-barriers

I have some OpenCL code that looks like this:

```
__kernel void calc(__global double* output) {
    size_t a = get_global_id(0);
    size_t b = get_global_id(1);
    double tot = 0.;
    if(a == b) {
        tot += f();
    }
    output[a * get_global_size(1) + b] = tot;
}
```

I.e., some work items take more time to execute than others. When I run this code on a GPU, everything works as expected. But when I run this on a Intel CPU, some of the output ends up incorrectly being `0.`. Could it be that some of the writes to global memory are overwriting others due to caching, etc? Do I need to place a barrier before or after a write to global memory?

Comment: Does cpu support 64 bit opencl kernel